# delete the second item that starts with the same substring

Tags: python, list

I have a list `l = ['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']`
I want to delete the elements that start with the same sub-string if they exist (in this case `'abcd'` and `'ghi'`).
**N.B: in my situation, I know that the 'repeated' elements, if they exist, can be only 'abcd' or 'ghi'.**
To delete them, I used this:

```
>>> l.remove('abcd') if ('abcdef' in l and 'abcd' in l) else l
>>> l.remove('ghi') if ('ghijklm' in l and 'ghi' in l) else l
>>> l
>>> ['abcdef', 'ghijklm', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
```

Is there a *more efficient* (or more automated) way to do this?

Comment: for me this sounds quite tricky, i think you need to fix at last the number of letters in the sub-string you want to compare with, otherwise with an automated loop everything would be deleted which starts for example with 'a' .

Comment: well if you sort first `'abcd'` will appear immediately before `'abcdef'` saving need for two loops

Comment: [**Prefix Tree / Trie**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) – theoretical improvement from `O(N^2)` to `O(NL)`, but only worth the overhead if `N` is large (and >> `L`).

Comment: do you need to check for "ABCDEF" only? Or do you also want to remove "ABCD" if "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" or "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ" might be in?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, as I said in the N.B, for my situation, there will not be "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" or "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ" , it is just "ABCDEF". in other words, **at most, only two elements in the list will have the same substring**.

Comment: Then only check for ABCDEF and if present remove ABCD (if there or not is not important, remove() will take care of it)- thats less work then checking for both orrucing and then removing it with your ternary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in linear time and O(n*m²) memory (where m is the length of your elements):

```
prefixes = {}
for word in l:
    for x in range(len(word) - 1):
        prefixes[word[:x]] = True

result = [word for word in l if word not in prefixes]
```

Iterate over each word and create a dictionary of the first character of each word, then the first two characters, then three, all the way up to all the characters of the word except the last one. Then iterate over the list again and if a word appears in that dictionary it's a shorter subset of some other word in the list

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that the `prefixes` set could become rather extensive for a longer list of longer words. A proper prefix-tree might use less space, but computational complexity should be about the same, and this is certainly much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']

for a in l[:]:
    for b in l[:]:
        if a.startswith(b) and a != b:
            l.remove(b)
print(l)
```

**Output**

```
['abcdef', 'ghijklm', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
```

Comment: O(N^2) is generally bad - only advantais is that you would get all of the duplicates if more then 1 exists.

Comment: simple solution - sort first, keep deleting if start matches (if exact found)

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you described.

```
your_list = ['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
print("Original list: %s" % your_list)
helper_list = []
for element in your_list:
    for element2 in your_list:
        if element.startswith(element2) and element != element2:
            print("%s starts with %s" % (element, element2))
            print("Remove: %s" % element)
            your_list.remove(element)
print("Removed list: %s" % your_list)
```

Output:

```
Original list: ['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
abcdef starts with abcd
Remove: abcdef
ghijklm starts with ghi
Remove: ghijklm
Removed list: ['abcd', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
```

On the other hand, I think there is more simple solution and you can solve it with list comprehension if you want.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Allen's way

```py
l = ['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
i=0
l = sorted(l)
while True:
 try:
  if l[i] in l[i+1]:
   l.remove(l[i])
   continue
  i += 1
 except:
  break
print(l)
#['abcdef', 'ghijklm', 'pqrs', 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
l =['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        if len(i)>len(j) and j in i:
            l.remove(j)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
l = ['abcdef', 'abcd', 'ghijklm', 'ghi', 'xyz', 'pqrs']
if "abcdef" in l:  # only 1 check for containment instead of 2
    l = [x for x in l if x != "abcd"]  # to remove _all_ abcd
    # or
    l = l.remove("abcd")               # if you know there is only one abcd in it
```

This might be slightly faster (if you have far more elements then you show) because you only need to check once for "abcdef" - and then once untile the first/all of list for replacement.

> ```
> >>> l.remove('abcd') if ('abcdef' in l and 'abcd' in l) else l
> ```

checks `l` twice for its full size to check containment (if unlucky) and then still needs to remove something from it

---

DISCLAIMER:
If this is NOT *proven, measured* bottleneck or security critical etc. I would not bother to do it *unless* I have measurements that suggests this  is the **biggest timesaver/optimization of all code** overall ... with lists up to some dozends/hundreds (tummy feeling - your data does not support any analysis) the estimated gain from it is negligable.